# Django Dictsort by __str__

Tags: django, templates

I have a project where one of the models is "Chassis".  I want to sort these chassis in django templates by the value returned by `__str__`.  If I write `|dictsort:"__str__"` it crashes.  I'm currently getting around this by writing a function `getIP` that returns the same thing as `__str__` and passing `|dictsort:"getIP"`.

Is there a way to do this without simply rewriting the exact same code in a different function?

Answer (score 1):

Why are sorting by that in the template?  Order in the view before you pass it out - generally try and keep business logic out of the templates where possible, and this sounds a lot like business logic.

As an example, one of my models:

```
class Event(models.Model):

    date = models.DateField()
    location_title = models.TextField()
    location_code = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    picture_url = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=250)
    event_url = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=250)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.event_url + " " + str(self.date)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.event_url = slugify(self.location_title+str(self.date))
        super(Event, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Given the output of `__str__` here is always going to be the event_url + some other stuff (as yours will be, presumably), I could use something along the lines of:

```
stuff_in_order = Event.objects.filter(#yourqueryhere).order_by('event_url').order_by('date')
```

This will have the same effect as munging the **str** method in your template to order your Chassis'. (sp?)

If you really need to reorder in the template, then you could use [regroup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup).

```
{% regroup chassis by dealer as dealer_list %}
```